# How to launch a child activity without pass through the parent activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

In my app I have to two activities and one background service. The first activity (Activity A) which is the main activity is used to start/stop the service. The service is used to start an activity (Activity B) when it is necessary to launch it (the service can launch activity B even if activity A is not running).

- When the servicees launch the activity B, I can see on the screen during a few milliseconds that the Activity A is launched and disappears just before that the Activity B is displayed.
- When `finish()` is called from the Activity B, this is the Activity A that is displayed on the screen and I wish to show the last activity launched before Activity B.

My question is how to launch activity B (as a standalone activity) from the service without pass through the activity A (which is the main activity)?

This is the code I used to launch Activity B from service :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

This is my manifest:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >        

    <!-- Activity A -->
    <activity
        android:name="ActivityA"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Activity B -->
    <activity
        android:name="ActivityB"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:immersive="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" />

    <!-- Service -->
    <service
        android:name="Service"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
    </service>
</application>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Just Place this code in your Activity A


 private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.d("Service","Message");
                ActivityA.this.finish();
            }
        };

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onResume();
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
                    mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("finishA"));
        }
```

//    Place this code in your Activity B onCreate() method

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

             Intent intent = new Intent("finishA");                    

             LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(ActivityB.this).sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But is there no other solution less tricky? By using manifest for example?

Comment: I know these solution only dude!! but you can finish any activity from background using this solution